# Error Updating plist file using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, plist

I'm trying to update a plist file using bash. For some strings I can update the plist file, but for some strings I get an error. For eg

```
defaults write '/Users/test/Desktop/myPlist'  'My Key' "[My Value]"
```

throws an error

```
2011-08-10 18:49:36.208 defaults[17287:903] Could not parse: [My Value].
Try single-quoting it.
```

Looks like the characters '[' and ']' seem to be throwing it off. How to make this work with the string "[My Value]"?

Comment: Maybe try single-quoting it...?

Answer (score 3):

You could try single-quoting it, like this:

```
defaults write '/Users/test/Desktop/myPlist'  'My Key' "\"[My Value]\""
```

Comment: 2011-08-10 19:05:44.531 defaults[17323:903] Could not parse: \'[My Value]\'.  Try single-quoting it.                                          Didnt work :(

Comment: This seemed to work:                                              defaults write '/Users/test/Desktop/myPlist'  'My Key' "\"[My Value]\""   Wonder why?

Comment: Alright, will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

None of the brackets and quotes are necessary and are not valid parts of a defaults write command.
Here's a valid defaults write command that works in a bash script:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari Homepage "http://google.com/"
```

here's a loop of defaults write commands I use to modify user templates on OS X:

```
for USER_TEMPLATE in "/System/Library/User Template"/*
do
    defaults write "${USER_TEMPLATE}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant DidSeeCloudSetup -bool TRUE
    defaults write "${USER_TEMPLATE}"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true
    defaults write "${USER_TEMPLATE}"/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist AppleKeyboardUIMode -int 3
done
```

So, your example correctly formatted would look like this:

```
defaults write /Users/test/Desktop/myplist MyKey MyValue
```

of course you'll need to add the appropriate switches if you want the key to be written as something other than a string- see the examples above for boolean and integer keys being written.

Finally, check the man page for the defaults command- it does a great job of going through all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can single quote escape your brackets by wrapping them in a double quote:

Instead of: `defaults write '/Users/test/Desktop/myPlist'  'My Key' "[My Value]"`

Do: `defaults write '/Users/test/Desktop/myPlist'  'My Key' "'[My Value]'"`

Notice the single quotes added to `[My Value]`